# KDB moving percentile using Swin function

Tags: list, function, kdb, percentile, sliding-window

I am trying to create a list of the 99th and 1st percentiles. Rather than a single percentile for today. I wanted percentiles for 500 days each using the prior 500 days. The functions I was using for this are the following

```
swin:{[f;w;s] f each { 1_x,y }\[w#0;s]}
percentile:{[x;y] y (100 xrank y:asc y) bin x}

swin[percentile[99;];500;List].
```

The issue I come across is that the 99th percentile calculates perfectly, but the 1st percentile makes the entire list = 0. a bit lost as to why it would do that. suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's causing the zeros is two-fold:

1. What behaviour do you want for the earliest 500 days when there isn't 500 days of history to work with? On day 1 there's only 1 datapoint, on day 2 only 2 etc. Only on the 500th day is there 500 days of actual data to work with. By default that `swin` function fills the gaps with some seed value
2. You're using zero as that seed value, aka `w#0`

For example a 5 day lookback on each date looks something like:

```
q)swin[::;5;1 2 3 4 5]
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 2
0 0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

You have zeros until you have data, so naturally the 1st percentile will pick up the zeros for the first roughly 500 dates.

So then you can decide to seed with a different value, or else possibly exclude zeros from your percentile function:

```
q)List:1000?1000
q)percentile:{[x;y] y (100 xrank y:asc y except 0) bin x}
q)swin[percentile[1;];500;List]
908 360 360 257 257 257 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90...
```

If zeros are a legitimate value in your list and can't be excluded then maybe seed the `swin` with some other value that you know won't be in the list (negatives? infinity? null?) and then exclude that seed from the percentile function.

EDIT: A final alternative is to use a different sliding window function which doesn't fill gaps with a seed value, e.g.

```
q)swin2:{[f;w;s] f each(),/:{neg[x]sublist y,z}[w]\[s]}
q)swin2[::;5;1 2 3 4 5]
,1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5

q)percentile:{[x;y] y (100 xrank y:asc y) bin x}
q)swin2[percentile[99;];500;List]
908 908 908 908 908 908 908 908 908 908 908 959 959..
q)swin2[percentile[1;];500;List]
908 360 360 257 257 257 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90..
```

Comment: Thank- you for your help here - apologies for the slow response. Swin2 is exactly what i was looking for. I did not want to exclude all 0's because even though rare, it could be a legitimate value.

Comment: hi Terry. coming back to this question, was wondering if you could help with another change. Id like it to not use todays observation within the distribution, any ideas how i can adapt the swin2 function to be able to do that?

Comment: In that case I think you would shift the input list using `prev` rather than adapting the swin2 function. If before you had something like `update pct:swin2[percentile[99;];500;List]from([]List)` you could have `update pct:swin2[percentile[99;];500;prev List]from([]List)`. This essentially lags everything by one day meaning todays record isn't in todays calc, however you now have to consider what this means for day 1 (zero observations to draw from)